# Set margin between legend items

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

Anybody use [RadLegend](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/features/radlegend-support)?

I want the vertical distance between the legend items is 10 px(maybe margin.bottom).

[image: legend]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an implicit `LegendItemControl` style:

```
<telerik:RadLegend Background="White" 
                   BorderBrush="Black" 
                   BorderThickness="1" 
                   Items="{Binding LegendItems, ElementName=chart1}" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <telerik:RadLegend.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:LegendItemControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:LegendItemControl}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 100" />
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadLegend.Resources>
</telerik:RadLegend>
```